# Is there a well-known nontrivial subset of NP for which it is known that it is a proper subset?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

It has been claimed that if $P = NP$, then every problem in $P$ (equivalently $NP$) is NP-complete.

As a blanket statement, I find this wrong because, well, there's the trivial problem or constant time problems, but more interestingly, I expect that there are classes that are very small that are provably not NP-complete but aren't entirely trivial. This is in analogy to the fact that it is known that $P != EXP$, there must be a $C \subsetneq NP$, presumably $C= NTIME(\log(n))$. But I have never heard discussed such a small class.

The smallest well-known class I can think of is $AC^0$, but I don't know whether it is known that it is not $NPC$. And there's Ryan's recent result that $NEXP \not\subset ACC^0$, which leads me to believe that it would have to be a much smaller class than $AC^0$ that would be known to be disctinct from $NP$.

I think the first statement might be considered to be true if all one has are deterministic polytime reductions (which would imply that -all- problems in $P$ are $P$-complete), but that seems to be too simplistic. A particular proof might use a particular reduction, but the distinctness of complexity classes is not parameterized by those reductions (or is it?).

So, thoughts/suggestions? Should I just accept the first statement since $NPC$ is defined with respect to deterministic polytime reductions? And even so, is there a well-known non-trivial class that is provably a proper subset of $NP$?

Comment: Parity∈NP∖AC0 implies that AC0 is a proper subset of NP.

Comment: Even closer, Parity∈ACC0 so AC0 is a proper subset of ACC0. Are there described classes between AC0 and ACC0 that might be relevant?

Comment: If P=NP then the power of the class is fully in the polynomial-time reduction, so the problem you are reducing to can be as trivial as you wish.

Comment: ...as long as it isn't the empty set or the set of all strings, to be pedantic. (The other constant-time solvable problems are fine though.)

Comment: @Antonio: You are right of course, one needs at least one "yes" and one "no" instance for the reduction to preserve structure.

Comment: @Antonio, @András: Can NP-completeness (with P reductions) be preserved using DLOGTIME reductions instead (or even more restricted reductions)? It just seems wrong to lump all the problems in P together.

Comment: @Mitch:  Cook's theorem relies on polynomial time reductions, so the answer is probably not.  The whole reason why NP-completeness is interesting with polynomial time reductions is because it's thought that P != NP; if P = NP, many things--such as talking about a "polynomial hierarchy" as its own class--would "seem wrong."  They would seem wrong because the assumption that P != NP would in that case be wrong.

Comment: @Philip: I'm not sure what of many things 'the answer is probably not' is referring to and in what direction.

Comment: You said, "Can NP-completeness be preserved using DLOGTIME reductions?"  I said, "probably not."

Comment: $AC^0$[p] is strict subset of NP, where $AC^0$[p] is $AC^0$ with mod p gates, and p is a prime. As for whether we can define NP-completeness to make it stricter, you can define it w.r.t., say, logspace reductions or even ACC reductions. As far as I know, it is not known if this changes the class NPC.

Comment: $\mathbf{SAT}$ is $\mathbf{NPC}$ even w.r.t. $\mathbf{DLogTime}$ reductions. I don't know what you mean by a reduction weaker than $\mathbf{DLogTime}$. It is so weak that it is not an interesting complexity class (it is strictly contained in $\mathbf{AC^0}$ which is equal to logarithmic-time hierarchy).

Comment: It is open if $\mathbf{ACC^0}$ is equal to $\mathbf{NP}$ so any class containing it will be open. So I think Robin's answer is the largest well-known class properly inside $\mathbf{NP}$.

Comment: @Robin, I think your comment is an answer.

Comment: Due to the non-deterministic time hierarchy theorem, any $NTIME( p(n)$ , where $p(n)$ is a polynomial, is a proper subset of $NP$ but I guess due to the formulation of your question you are not interested in $NTIME$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reposting my comment as an answer:

AC<sup>0</sup>[p] is strict subset of NP, where AC<sup>0</sup>[p] is AC<sup>0</sup> with mod p gates, and p is a prime.

As for whether we can define NP-completeness to make it stricter, you can define it w.r.t., say, logspace reductions or even ACC reductions. As far as I know, it is not known if this changes the class NPC. What is known, however, is that AC<sup>0</sup> reductions are not powerful enough. (Ref: [Reducing the complexity of reductions](http://www.springerlink.com/content/bbar426549dv33ut/) by M. Agrawal, E. Allender, R. Impagliazzo, T. Pitassi and S. Rudich)

Comment: Is it known if there are problems in $AC^0[p]$ or even $AC^0$ that are definitely not NPC?

Comment: @Mitch, yes (under suitable reductions), an $\mathbf{NP}$ problem can be reduced to an $\mathbf{NPC}$ problem, so these classes being different from $\mathbf{NP}$ implies that they also different from $\mathbf{NPC}$, i.e. non of them is $\mathbf{NPC}$. On the other hand, if you are using $\mathbf{P}$ reductions, then as long as it is possible to have $\mathbf{P=NP}$, all problems in $\mathbf{P}$ including those in these classes will be $\mathbf{NPC}$.

Answer (score 10):

[Answering the original motivating issue: "Should I just accept the first statement since NPC is defined with respect to deterministic polytime reductions?"]

First, if $P=NP$ but the Berman-Hartmanis Isomorphism Conjecture fails, then there are infinitely many distinct p-isomorphism classes of languages within $P$. So even though it is true that $P=NP$ implies all sets in $P$ are $NP$-complete with respect to polynomial-time reduction (technical caveat below), that does not mean that we lose all information about $P$. By looking at a finer type of reduction -- but still polynomial-time, namely polynomial-time computable-and-invertible length-increasing one-one reductions -- we can potentially tell a lot about what's going on inside $P$.

In fact, if $P=NP$ but the Isomorphism Conjecture fails, then the partially ordered set of p-isomorphism classes inside $P$ is quite rich: any countable partial order can be embedded in it (see [P. Young. Some structural properties of polynomial reducibilities and sets in NP. STOC 1983.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/800061.808770)).

But more generally, in some cases it does feel wrong to lump all of $P$ together and in other cases it's exactly what you want. This is why, for example, we don't use poly-time reductions when discussing $L$ versus $P$, but we do when discussing $P$ versus $NP$. But there might be another class you want to contrast with $NP$ where it makes sense to use other reductions. The type of reduction you use should be the type you need for the problem at hand; there is no "single right reduction" to define, e.g., $NP$-completeness (though "$NP$-complete" without qualification usually means w.r.t. poly-time many-one reductions, but that is a matter of convention).

Distinctness of complexity classes is not parametrized by reductions; however, there are several potentially distinct classes that could legitimately be called "$NP$-complete," namely for any reducibility $r$, "$NP$-complete with respect to $r$-reductions".

(Caveat: If we use poly-time many-one reductions, then $\emptyset$ and $\Sigma^{*}$ do not become $NP$-complete if $P=NP$. If we use poly-time Turing reductions, or even poly-time 1-tt reductions, they do.)

Comment: It's funny but my actual motivating question is not the 'if P=NP, then P=NPC', rather the strictness separation of classes in the hierarchy. And your answer helps with both.

Answer (score 0):

Both the (current) answers plus the comments answer all together. I thought I'd summarize here.

- Completeness for a class is defined variably with respect to a given class; for example, NPC is usually defined wrt detpolytime (P) reductions, but sometimes also L (logspace) or even DLOGTIME (and SAT is NPC for all of these).
- There are known nontrivial proper subclasses of NP ($AC^0[p]$).

So the claim made in the first sentence of my OP is true, but only with the common assumption of P-reductions.